# Using UUIDs in mongoose for ObjectID references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I'm building a CRUD-style REST service with Node.js, Express and MongoDB using mongoose.  This service is going to allow users of an already existing android application to upload/sync the contents of their individual databases online.

The data model for the already-existing application uses UUIDs (generated in Java) which clashes with the shorter, monotonic MongoDB style `_id` fields.  Because the data model already exists and is  populated with data from many users, I cannot convert the source data over to monotonic MongoDB-style `_id`s.  This has left me with 2 options that I can think of: either 1) Make Mongo/Mongoose (or some other ODM) play nicely with full UUIDs instead of the monotonic `_id`s or 2) add a uuid field to the mongoose model in addition to the `_id` field and fight the pitfalls of this approach.  I'm attempting to choose option #1 and running into issues with ObjectID references.

I originally stumbled upon [mongoose-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-uuid), but unfortunately this isn't working for my use-case properly because it was overwriting my explicitly-set `_id` value when creating new Mongoose objects.  Diving into the plugin code, it assumes that an object is new (by calling checking Mongoose's `.isNew` value) and thus overwrites the `_id` with a new uuid.  Since I need to retain the original uuid when creating new documents in Mongo, this plugin isn't working for me.

Next, I found a [post](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1026) by Aaron Heckmann, creator of mongoose, on a similar topic.  This has been helpful, however I am now encountering the problem where I cannot have my mongoose schemas reference each other by ObjectID, since they technically they are now referencing each other using String `_ids.

Schema example:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var trackPassSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, default: function genUUID() {
        uuid.v1()
    }},
    //Omitting other fields in snippet for simplicity
    vehicle: [
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Vehicle'}
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('TrackPass', trackPassSchema);
```

Referencing schema:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var vehicleSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, default: function genUUID() {
        uuid.v1()
    }},
    //Omitting other fields in snippet for simplicity
    description: {type: String},
    year: {type: Number}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vehicle', vehicleSchema);
```

When I attempt to call `save()` a trackPass that has been passed in from my application:

```js
var trackPass = new TrackPass(req.body);

//Force the ID to match what was put into the request
trackPass._id = req.params.id;
trackPass.save(function (err) { ... }
```

I get the following error:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "b205ac4d-fd96-4b1e-892a-d4fab818ea2a" at path "vehicle"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "b205ac4d-fd96-4b1e-892a-d4fab818ea2a" at path "vehicle"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: ["b205ac4d-fd96-4b1e-892a-d4fab818ea2a"],
  path: 'vehicle' }
```

I believe this error makes sense as I'm now using Strings which are longer than typical Mongo ObjectIDs.  Without having the ObjectID reference, I don't believe I will be able to `populate()` referenced objects from other collections.  I suppose I could simply not reference the other nested objects in my schema definitions, however I don't like this approach as I feel I will be losing a lot of the benefit of utilizing the ODM.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can still use `populate()` with `_id` values of types besides ObjectID, but you do need to use the same type in the reference definition.

So your `trackPassSchema` would need to change to:

```
var trackPassSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, default: function genUUID() {
        return uuid.v1()
    }},
    vehicle: [
        {type: String, required: true, ref: 'Vehicle'}
    ]
});
```

As Adam notes in the comments, you could simplify your `default` value to:

```
var trackPassSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
    vehicle: [
        {type: String, required: true, ref: 'Vehicle'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: You could simplify this a little: `_id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1}`

Comment: @AdamC your suggestion would make the generated uuid be constant during the lifetime of this object.

Comment: No, it's good. `default: uuid.v1()` would have that problem, but not `default: uuid.v1`.

Comment: @Sash Yes, as @JohnnyHK mentioned, we are instructing mongoose to execute the `uuid.v1` function to generate the default value as needed - we are not actually executing the function directly.

Answer (score 3):

Both JohnnyHK and Adam C answers are correct. But if you're using uuid in schema for an array of objects, it is good to use it like this

```
var trackPassSchema = new Schema({
_id: { type: String, default: () => uuid.v1 },
vehicle: [
    {type: String, required: true, ref: 'Vehicle'}
]
```

});

Because, in one such scenario when i tried using like this  `_id: { type: String, default: () => uuid.v1 }` multiple objects of the array had the same id.

It is not possible in this case as _id is unique field, but it can happen when you are using with fields that aren't unique.