# using uuid as objectID in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, uuid

How can i use an UUID generated string,  instead of the original mongoose ObjectID string , keeping the objectID methods(ValueOf(), To String(), ....) ?

when i generate UUID and i try to use in my mongoose schema with

in my model:

```
var uniqueUUID = uuid.v4();
createUser = user({
            'myid': uniqueUUID,
});
```

in my model/schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId

});
```

got a validation error.

```
ValidationError: user validation failed
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438882/using-uuids-in-mongoose-for-objectid-references

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a key that doesn't exist in the schema. There is no `myid` key defined in your schema. By default mongoose doesn't allow keys that haven't been pre-defined.

You can change it up to be something like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

_id: {type: String, default: uuid.v4}

});
```

That automaticly assings the object id with the generated `uuid.v4` value.

When creating user use:

```
var newUser = new user();
```

That has automaticly assigned the id for the document. Just remeber to save it. :)

If you want to have another id field called `myid` you can add that to the schema by following how the _id has been added.

Comment: Okay, I have made a mistake on my code. _id type should be String. Editing it now.