# Node.js can not set default UUID with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, uuid

I was trying to define a default UUID in mongoose / Node.js / Express for my 
_id field in my Schema Model...

```
/**Demonstrator
 * 
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var uuid = require('node-uuid')
require('mongoose-uuid2')(mongoose);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);
var Status = require('./Status');
var StatusSchema = Status.Schema; 
var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
var UUID = mongoose.Types.UUID;

var DemonstratorSchema = new Schema({
    //_id: SchemaTypes.Long;
    _id: { type: String, default: uuidv4()},
    id2: SchemaTypes.Long,
    Test: String,    
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Demonstrator", DemonstratorSchema);
console.log("DemonstratorSchema created!");
```

I was also trying to write an own function like in this post:
[Using UUIDs in mongoose for ObjectID references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438882/using-uuids-in-mongoose-for-objectid-references), but this didnt work either... it just won't create a default generated UUID with mongoose in my database, why?

EDIT: I just found out, it creates a UUID or String field with a 32byte UUID value, I just wasn't able to do this in the mongo shell directly, although I thought my Schema kind of enforces this, but its logical that this was nonsense, because the mongo Shell is not aware of anything of my backend constraints ;) sorry about that.... but is it also safe to assume, that anything coming from an REST API endpoint (POST) that is generated and saved in my backend, will have automatically created UUID?

And what is recommended to use as UUID version? v1? or rather v4 or  even v5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `default` property should be a function that returns a string (in your case, a UUIDv4 value).

That's not what your schema provides, though:

```
_id: { type: String, default: uuidv4()}
```

That declaration will run the `uuidv4` function, which returns a string, *and use that string as the default*. It's similar to this:

```
_id: { type: String, default: 'FA6281FF-5961-4F2F-8270-D6AB9954410D'}
```

Instead, pass it a reference to the `uuidv4` function:

```
_id: { type: String, default: uuidv4 }
```

That way, each time a default value is required, Mongoose will call that function, which will return a new UUID every time.

Comment: ok it works that way, but yet another question: if I define type as UUID, it creates UUID's in a binary form I think, like the ObjectId's: UUID("FA6281FF-5961-4F2F-8270-D6AB9954410D"), what is the advantage of this? Is it faster to index those keys compared to Strings, or do they save more space and are they faster in querying? Should I use UUID type or prefer strings? And is it easier to query for UUID's or Strings ? And are string queries for UUIDs converted automatically into UUID type queries then?

Comment: @user2883596 your questions are mostly explained in the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-uuid2#what-does-it-do): _"When used instead of String, UUIDs will be stored in Binary format, which takes about half as much space."_ and _"It automatically casts Strings to Binary, and when read a document from the database, and you access a property directly, you get the value back as a String."_.

Comment: cool thanks for the link, so from that I infer it would be better to use UUID datatype

Comment: @user2883596 yeah, it will save you some space and it doesn't sound like there would be any performance impact when using it.